# python 3.x shelve except keyerror wheras key in dict is true

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, shelve, keyerror

I'm strugglning with a weird problem in python 3.x with shelve.
The concept is, morphological forms of lemma are used to find suitable paradigms based on those forms, shelve is used.

`guessexpl` is shelve, `ntrf` is key.
The problem is, that I have the key: `'\tk1gMnSc2[^:]*::a k1gMnPc1[^:]*:k:ci k1gMnPc6[^:]*:k:cích'` (define morphological forms) and `ntrf in guessexpl` return `True`, but `print(guessexpl[ntrf])` raises an exception.

Code:

```
print('ntrf in expl',ntrf in guessexpl, 'ntrf in guesser',ntrf in guesser)
if ntrf in guessexpl:
    print('print guessexpl[ntrf]')
    print(guessexpl[ntrf])
```

After patching `shelve` to use the Python unpickler rather than the C version with:

```
import shelve
import pickle
# Use the Python implementation, not the C extension, to debug.
shelve.Unpickler = pickle._Unpickler
```

the error I get is:

```
ntrf in expl True ntrf in guesser True
print guessexpl[ntrf]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
    value = self.cache[key]
KeyError: '\tk1gMnSc2[^:]*::a k1gMnPc1[^:]*:k:ci k1gMnPc6[^:]*:k:cích'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent cal
  File "./scripts/lntrf2lpn_editing.py", line 363, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "./scripts/lntrf2lpn_editing.py", line 311, in main
    print(guessexpl[ntrf])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/shelve.py", line 114, in __getitem__
    value = Unpickler(f).load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/pickle.py", line 834, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/pickle.py", line 1158, in load_long_binget
    self.append(self.memo[i])
KeyError: -1493160213
```

reproducable sample

```
>>> a['\tk1gMnSc2[^:]*::a k1gMnPc1[^:]*:k:ci k1gMnPc6[^:]*:k:cích'][0]
{'Soustružník': [((184, (('Azték', 'nM'),)), {'Soustružník'})], 'soustružník': [((2260, (('vlk', ''),)), {'soustružník', 'kovosoustružník'})]}

>>> a['\tk1gMnSc2[^:]*::a k1gMnPc1[^:]*:k:ci k1gMnPc6[^:]*:k:cích'][1]
{'oustružník': [((2260, (('vlk', ''),)), {'soustružník', 'kovosoustružník'}), ((184, (('Azték', 'nM'),)), {'Soustružník'})], 'kolomazník': [((2260, (('vlk', ''),)), {'kolomazník'})], 'Kolomazník': [((184, (('Azték', 'nM'),)), {'Kolomazník'})]}
```

Explanation: There is list of dict for the ntrf. The point of list is length of lemma. Dict is made of lemma's ending:[(frequency of paradigm group, (paradigm group)), set of associated lemmas]...paradigm group consist of paradigm and note touples.

Honestly, I have no idea what's going on. Input is in utf-8. If shelve files are deleted, everything works just fine. But this is not the solution.

Comment: The key is there, but the *stored pickle* for the key is invalid. What did you store in the shelve for that key?

Comment: there is file.close() at the end. So it should be synchronised. But It wans't me who run the script and cause invalid stored pickle. User may teminated proces with ctrl+c and file.close() wasn't executed.

Comment: The file is closed regardless, and that's not the issue here.

Comment: Your pickle is either invalid (bug in pickle) or your data on-disk has been corrupted. Without a way to reproduce your error we cannot say anything else though. Show us a *reproducable* sample of what you stored in the shelve.

Comment: ok, sample has been added. This is what it should look like(shelve files was rebuild into new files without error. The old ones are still corrupted). Have you an idea what could possibly cause corruption of file?

Comment: Any number of things; binary file being treated as text when using FTP, other processes not treating it as binary, random disk problems, etc.

Comment: Are you saying you cannot reproduce the issue now? Because I don't see any steps I can follow to trigger the same exception.

Comment: yes, that is another problem. I mentioned it in another answer, but user deleted it. It is in the last paragraph ,,if I delete shelve files, everything works fine". After I rebuild it, it works. And I have no idea what could cause this problem. Bug in script/some modue or user who run this and corrupt the data somehow.

Comment: I am the user that deleted that post, as it wasn't an answer but a means to help you debug this. Again, without access to the steps to reproduce this we cannot help.

Comment: yeah, I have thought so. Question was like, if anyone has a clue how this could be caused, because I have no idea. Like someone deleted it on disc, but this is very unlikely